# Hausdorff dimension of a connected set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: connectedness, dimension-theory-analysis

I have been looking for certain properties of the Hausdorff dimension lately, and noticed that all the examples I know of in $\mathbb{R}$ are only totally disconnected spaces. So I was wondering whether any subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\dim(A)<1$ must be disconnected or even totally disconnected?

Are there counter-examples to these 'conjectures'? Or perhaps some known results on this subject which are relevant?

Comment: Well, what if $A$ contains an interval?

Comment: @ArcticChar Then it must be of dimension $1$. My Question is more, if $A$ has dimension strictly less than $1$, can it be connected? I can't think of such examples.

Comment: If it is connected, then it contains an interval... (indeed, then it is an interval)

Comment: @ArcticChar I forgot that connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are generalised intervals. Do you know whether a set has to be to totally disconnected, as well?

Comment: The connected sets in $\mathbb R$ are the intervals.  A more advanced fact: the Hausdorff dimension in a metric space is ${}\ge{}$ the topological dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\subset \mathbb R$ and $\dim A <1$, then $A$ has to be totally disconnected: if not, then one of the connected component of $A$ is not a one point set. Then that connected component contains an interval, which contradicts to the assumptions that $\dim A <1$.

Note that there are totally disconnected subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$ with $\dim B = 1$: for example $B = \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This question seems silly in hindsight.