# Hausdorff dimension of a connected set in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: connectedness, path-connected, dimension-theory-analysis

I recently asked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243152/hausdorff-dimension-of-a-connected-set-in-mathbbr), whether a set $A$ not being  totally disconnected  in $\mathbb{R}$ implies $\dim(A)=1$? The answer I was given, showed that the answer is yes by relatively simple arguments.

My follow-up question, is

> **Does connectedness of $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ imply a lower estimate on the dimension of $\dim (A)$, in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d>1$ when $\vert A \vert\geq 1$?**

whether connectedness implies a lower estimate on the dimension of a set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d>1$?
I think that if $A$ is path connected, then $\dim(A)\geq 1$, but to conclude this I need to be sure that curves in $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfy $\dim\geq 1$. Since the arguments in $1$-dimension were simpler than I suspected, I thought that perhaps the arguments here would be relatively simpler as well?

Is there a lower estimate on $\dim(A)$ when $A$ is path connected? Is there also an estimate when $A$ is just connected?

Comment: There is a sketch proof for $d=2$ in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64484/hausdorff-dimension-of-connected-closed-subsets-of-r2). Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem**: if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is connected and $|A| > 1$, then $\operatorname{dim}(A) \geqslant 1$.

**Proof.** Without loss of generality $0 \in A$ and $p \in A$, where $p = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$. It suffices to show that for any $d < 1$ we have that $\mathcal{H}^d(A) = \infty$ where

$$\mathcal{H}^d(A) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \inf \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} r_i^d : A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B(x_i, r_i) \text{ for some } x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d, \ 0 < r_i < r \right\}.$$

Fix $r \in (0, 1)$ and consider any family of balls $\left< B(x_i, r_i) : i \in \mathbb{N} \right>$ covering $A$ where $0 < r_i < r$. Denote by $\pi : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ the projection onto the first coordinate.

By the connectedness of $A$, for each $t \in (0, 1)$ the hyperplane $\{ t \} \times \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ must intersect $A$ in some point $p_t$ and this point is covered by some ball $B(x_i, r_i)$. Therefore  the family $\mathcal{I} = \left< \pi \big[ B(x_i, r_i) \big] : i \in \mathbb{N} \right>$ is a covering of $(0, 1)$ with one-dimensional balls of radii $0 < r_i < r$. But we know that $\mathcal{H}^d \big( (0, 1) \big) = \infty$ (because $d < 1$), hence for sufficiently small $r$ we must have that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} r_i^d$ is arbitrarily big. That finishes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thannk youu for your answer, but there are few details which I do not fully understand.
Your proof seems to imply that $A\cap (0,1)\times \mathbb{R}^d=(0,1)$, which does not necessarily work. $A$ could be even the hyperplane ${0}\times \mathbb{R}^d$, whose projection has Hausdorff dimension zero. It seems like it could be modified to consider any axis though.

Comment: Writing "without loss of generality $0 \in A$ and $p \in A$" I mean: $A$ contains at least two points and we can choose the coordinate system so that the first of them is $0$ and the second is $p$. And after this reduction it must be the case that the projection of $A$ contains $(0, 1)$. Also $A \cap \big[ (0, 1) \times \mathbb{R}^d \big] = (0, 1)$ is not implied by the proof.

Comment: Okay,I must have missed that line. Thanks again.